# System.AccessViolationException thrown by Visual C# on call to Lapack inside wrapped C++\CLI dll

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, lapack

I have written some code in native C++ which makes calls to fortran routines of the blas and lapack library (linked as dll's). The native code runs fine, with no compiler or runtime errors or warnings.

Now, I was trying to wrap the native C++ into a dll to use in the .NET framework, so I started a Visual C++ project, wrote a wrapper ref class, compiled this into a dll and included that dll into a C# project.

After I finally managed to get the C# project to compile, I tried to run it. But I get a runtime error at the first call to a lapack routine! (i.e. at the line `dpbtrf_( &LOWER, &n, &izero, D.data(), &ione, &info );` in Test.cpp)

The error says:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
 Source=DotNetTest
```

Am I missing some compiler option? 
Or is there really corrupt memory which the native C++ compiler\runtime did not see? 
Any tips on how to debug this?

Thanks a lot!

Here's a tiny reproduction that generates the same problem as the original code (which is too extensive to post here):

1. the native C++ Test.h:

```
    #ifndef TEST_H_INCLUDED
    #define TEST_H_INCLUDED

    #include <vector>

    namespace NativeTest
    {
        class Test
        {
            public:
                Test( int size );
                ~Test();

                void set( int i, double d );
                double get( int i ) const;
                int chol();
            private:
                std::vector<double> D;
                int n;
        }; // class Test
    } // namespace NativeTest

    #endif // TEST_H_INCLUDED
```

1. the native C++ Test.cpp (included in the VC++ project) (!EDITTED with __cdecl):

```
    #include "Test.h"

    using namespace NativeTest;

    const int ione = 1;
    const int izero = 0;
    const char LOWER = 'L';

    extern "C"
    {
        // factorization for banded matrix
        void __cdecl dpbtrf_( const char *UPLO, const int *N, const int *KD,
                              double *AB, const int *LDAB, int *INFO );
    }

    Test::Test( int size ) : n( size )
    { D.resize( n ); }

    Test::~Test() { }

    void Test::set( int i, double d ) { D[ i ] = d; }

    double Test::get( int i ) const { return D[ i ]; }

    int Test::chol()
    {
        int info = 0;
        dpbtrf_( &LOWER, &n, &izero, D.data(), &ione, &info );
        return info;
    }
```

1. The C++\CLI wrapper:

```
    // TestNet.h

    #pragma once
    #include "Test.h"

    using namespace System;

    namespace DotNetTest {

        public ref class TestNet
        {
            public:
                TestNet( int size ) { test = new NativeTest::Test( size ); }
                ~TestNet() { this->!TestNet(); }
                !TestNet() { delete test; test = NULL; }

                void set( int i, double d ) { test->set( i, d ); }
                double get( int i ) { return test->get( i ); }
                int chol() { return test->chol(); }

            protected:
                NativeTest::Test * test;                
        };
    }
```

1. The C# call:

```
    DotNetTest.TestNet t = new DotNetTest.TestNet(2);
    t.set(0, 2);
    t.set(1, 3);
    int info = t.chol();
```

Comment: When I say that "the native code runs fine, with no compiler or runtime errors or warnings", I mean that it does so in Code::Blocks with a gcc compiler en MinGW. I have not actually tried to run it from Visual C++. I did copy the lapack, blas and mingw dll's to the bin directory of the C# application. I'm not sure how this relates to a possible solution, but I thought this might complete the problem description. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed, at least for the test code posted here. I wrongly added the gcc-compiled lapack\blas binaries, the same as I used for my original project (which also used gcc).

Today, I downloaded the precompiled binaries for windows [from here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/), put those in the bin folder of my C# project (together with the 3 MinGW dll's: libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll, libgfortran-3.dll and libquadmath-0.dll) and made sure the Visual C++\CLI project used the same libraries to link to (by setting the Additional Link Directory to the C# bin folder). This fixed it, and I got the result I wanted (no access violation and the calculation was correct).

I also removed the /clr flag in the compile options for the Test.cpp file, and switch the 'Use precompiled headers' off for that file.